# How can I store and restore the scroll position of a grid in my own Joomla component?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, parameters, components, hidden

I am developing a Joomla component with a (very common) grid view in de administrator part. When I click on the publish icon of an item in the grid, the page will be reloaded and the publish state will be changed to published/unpublished. But after the page has been reloaded, I would like the grid to scroll to the scroll position it was at when I clicked the publish icon, so I can see the item that I just changed.

I have tried to achieve this storing and restoring of the scroll position almost completely analogue to the way the search filter is stored/restored between page loads:

1) In the template (views/mygrid/tmpl/default.php) I added a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_scroll" value="0" id="page_scroll" />
```

2) In the same file I added some code to the onsubmit attribute of the form to fill this field:

```
<form id="adminForm" name="adminForm" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('page_scroll').value = window.pageYOffset;">
```

3) In the model (models/mygrid.php, class extend from JModelList) I added these lines to the populateState function:

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
  ..
  $pageScroll = $app->getUserStateFromRequest( $this->context.'.page.scroll', 'page_scroll', '0', 'string');
  $this->setState( 'page.scroll', $pageScroll );
  ..
}
```

4) In the view (views/mygrid/view.html.php, class extended from JView) I added this line in the display function:

```
function display($tpl = null) {
..
  $this->state = $this->get('State');
..
}
```

5) And, finally, back in the template (views/mygrid/tmpl/default.php), I added this little script at the end of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.scrollTo( 0, <?php echo $this->state->get('page.scroll') ?> );
</script>
```

It looks so nice and clean and correct to me, but it just refuses to work. When I add the following debug line to that last script, it just gives me 0 all the time:

```
alert( <?php echo $this->state->get('page.scroll') ?> );
```

Can somebody tell me what I am overlooking? I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Logic makes sense to me. I would just start echoing/alerting the value after each step to make sure it makes it to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encouraged by David Fritsch, I debugged again very thoroughly and found the answer! Not one, but two things were going wrong! For people with the same problem, or to complete this 'manual' for anyone that also wants page scrolling stored/restored, I will explain:

1) This first thing is the most important. When you apply a filter in the 'mygrid' view, the form is submitted and immediately loads the same view again, but now with the new filtering applied. That's why step 3 in my question works fine for the filters.

But... when you click the publish state of a grid item, the form is submitted, but now with the task 'mygriditem.publish' or 'mygriditem.unpublish'! Therefore step 3 of my answer is not reached, because the 'mygriditem' controller is now called instead of the 'mygrid' controller. And only after that, the page is reloaded a second time to redirect back to the 'mygrid' view. But then 'page_scroll' is no longer in the request!!

**Solution:** step 3 in my question has to be copied to the publish task function of the mygriditem controller (controllers/mygriditem.php, class extend from JControllerForm), like:

```
public function publish( $key = null, $urlVar = null )
{
    JFactory::getApplication()->getUserStateFromRequest( 'com_mycomponent.mygrid.page.scroll', 'page_scroll', '0', 'string' );

    return parent::publish( $key, $urlVar );
}
```

After doing the same thing with the 'unpublish' function it works!!

2) There is also a second thing that I overlooked, which made it very confusing: the onsubmit event handler of a form is only executed when clicking on a submit button, not when you submit the form with Javascript like:

```
onclick="this.form.submit()"
```

I feel I should keep this short. Joomla provides in a function, which let you use this in your template (views/mygrid/tmpl/default.php) instead:

```
onclick="submitform(task)"
```

Be aware to use this function (indirectly) to submit the adminForm, then the onsubmit event handler will be executed.

I hope this will be helpful to somebody. :)